# Magento $_productCollection foreach loop

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to change the foreach loop a bit for the theme I am editing.

The $i iterator seems to count to 10 and then reset. I am not sure where this is set though.

I have a feeling it is based on the $_productCollection.

I want to change the loop to restart at 18 instead of 10. I have echoed the $i iterator to see what is going on and I can see that at 10 the loop starts over again. where is the collectionsize set? I tried changing the values in the magento admin under configuration>Catalog>catalog to 9,18,27
But that does not seem to work.

Here is the foreach loop:

```
$i=0; 
    echo "collectsize" . $_collectionSize 
    ?>
    <div id="products-grid">

    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):?>

        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid columns<?php echo $_columnCount; if($_config['product_list_style'] == 1) echo " boxed"; if((($i-1)/$_columnCount)%2) echo " even"; else echo " odd"; if($i==1) echo " first"; if($i+$_columnCount > $_collectionSize) echo " last"; ?>">       
        <?php endif ?>

            <li class="item<?php if($_config['product_list_style'] == 1) echo" boxed"; if($_columnCount == 9) { $imgSize = $smallImgSize; $trimSize = $smallImgTrimSize; $imgHeight = $smallImgHeight; } if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): if($_columnCount == 9) { $imgSize = $bigImgSize; $trimSize = $bigImgTrimSize; $imgHeight = $bigImgHeight; } ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>" id="item-id-<?php echo $_product->getId()?>">
            <?php  echo "i:". $i; ?>
                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($_showGallery): 
                        $_thumbs = $_listMedia->setTemplate("catalog/product/list/mediaall.phtml")->setData('product', $_product)->toHtml();
                            if($_thumbs != 'null' && $_thumbs): ?>
                                <div class="gallery-display"><div class="gallery-display-overlay"><?php echo $_thumbs; ?></div></div>
                        <?php endif; 
                endif; ?>
                <?php $mainImg = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgSize, $imgHeight); ?>
                <?php if($_hoverSwap): $backImg = $_listMedia->setTemplate("catalog/product/list/media.phtml")->setData('size', $imgSize)->setData('height', $imgHeight)->setData('product', $_product)->toHtml(); endif; ?>            

                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <?php if($backImg != 'null' && $backImg): ?><img src="<?php echo $backImg ?>" class="hover-image" width="<?php echo $imgSize ?>" height="<?php echo $imgHeight ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /><?php endif; ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgSize, $imgHeight) ?>" <?php if($backImg != 'null' && $backImg): ?>class="hover-main-image" <?php endif; ?> width="<?php echo $imgSize ?>" height="<?php echo $imgHeight ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                </a>

                <div class="moreinfo">
                    <div class="addto">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <?php if (!($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($_product) || $_product->isGrouped())) { ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="btn-cart<?php if($_ajaxAddToCart) echo " ajax-addtocart" ?>"<?php if($_ajaxAddToCart): ?> data-id="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></a>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <a href="<?php if($_ajaxAddToCart) echo $this->getUrl('ajax/index/options',array('product_id'=>$_product->getId())); else echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="btn-cart<?php if($_ajaxAddToCart) echo " btn-quickview" ?>"<?php if($_ajaxAddToCart): ?> data-id="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></a>
                            <?php }  ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <span class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_addToWishlist || $_addToCompare || $_quickView){ $_i = 0; ?>
                            <ul class="add-to-links">
                                <?php if ($_addToWishlist && $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                    <li<?php if(!$_i++): ?> class="last"<?php endif; ?>><a title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>" href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist" data-id="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($_addToCompare && $_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                    <li<?php if(!$_i++): ?> class="last"<?php endif; ?>><a title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare" data-id="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($_quickView): ?>
                                    <li<?php if(!$_i++): ?> class="last"<?php endif; ?>><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('ajax/index/options', array('product_id'=>$_product->getId())); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Quick View') ?>" class="btn-quickview" data-id="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Quick View') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php } ?>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="moreinfo-labels"><?php include('view/labels.phtml'); ?></div>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'), $length = $trimSize, $etc = '...', $remainder = '', $breakWords = true); ?></a></h2>
                    <div id='productname<?php echo $_product->getId()?>' style='display:none'><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></div>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
<?php echo " column:".$_columnCount; echo "collectsize:" . $_collectionSize ;?> 
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Edit:

So I went into the catalog.xml file and found these lines which I think are important here:

```
<action ifconfig="milanoconfig/product_list/infinite_scroll" method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>5</limit></action>
                    <action ifconfig="milanoconfig/product_list/infinite_scroll" method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>5</limit></action>
                    <action ifconfig="milanoconfig/product_list/infinite_scroll" method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit helper="ThemeConfig/getISGridPageLimit" /></action>
                    <action ifconfig="milanoconfig/product_list/infinite_scroll" method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit helper="ThemeConfig/getISGridPageLimit" /></action>
```

So being a magento newbie... Where exactly do I find where this ThemeConfig directory is located?

Comment: Please post your catalog.xml file. This will tell us where the block is. Also @Sackling, post what page this is (product view page, category page, etc...)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right place. I made an edit which I think includes the relevant portion of catalog.xml. The page is the category page. I am editing list.phtml